# flash as3 adding focus listener to an input text field

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hi I'm trying to use the following code to add a listener to a text field which clears the field, but I'm getting the error:

"Parameter Listener Must be Non-Null"

This is the code I'm using:

```
//pos is the instance name of the textfield
    var posText = currCard.cardBack.pos;
    posText.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearText);
    posText.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;


    currCard.hit.visible = false;

    function clearText(e:MouseEvent) {
        trace ("clear");
        //posHolder = posText.text;
        //posText.text = "";
    }
```

I should add that this text fields starts out on stage as a dynamic text field. In the code above I am changing its type to input, so that might affect things.

I am trying to set up the field so that when a user clicks in the text field, a cursor movie clip appears, and the text that was in the field is erased, and that when they leave the text field and click elsewhere, the text is accepted, the textfield converts back to a dynamic field, essentially "locking" the entered text into the field.

Comment: What is the goal you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var tfDynamic:TextField = new TextField( )
stage.addChild(tfDynamic )
tfDynamic.width = 100
tfDynamic.height = 20
tfDynamic.x = 10
tfDynamic.y = 10
tfDynamic.border = true
tfDynamic.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
tfDynamic.text = "hello";


tfDynamic.addEventListener(FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT, onFocusOut)
var savedText:String 
function onFocusOut( e:FocusEvent ):void{
    trace('onFocusOut')
    savedText =  tfDynamic.text
    tfDynamic.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;

}

tfDynamic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onclick )
function onclick( e:MouseEvent ):void{
    trace('onclick')
    tfDynamic.text = "";
    tfDynamic.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
}
```

Comment: yeah - that's the thing - when I add a listener to my text field for click, I get the "parameter must be non-null" error. I think it has to do with the fact that the text field starts as dynamic and gets changed to be an input field.

Comment: The code I supplied is a fully functional example on what you are trying to get done. The only other thing that could give the error you are getting is the posText object is null, meaning you are not referencing it properly. Have you tried to trace posText right after you assign it?

Comment: ah - I think the problem was that my onClick function did not specify a return type (:void). Thanks!

Comment: That would give you are warning return value for function XXXX has no type declaration.

Answer (score 2):

If I had to clear the textfield, I would use **`FOCUS_IN`**. If you use `onclick`, when the textfield has focus and you click on it again, the textfield will be clear again... I'm not sure that what you want.

Here is the [FocusEvent reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/FocusEvent.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6)

Answer (score 1):

i wouldn't recommend using "MouseEvent.CLICK" in such case, use "FocusEvent.FOCUS_OUT" instead since field might be selected using Tab key